# Flutter Algolia search TextField with debounce

Tags: flutter, dart, algolia, debouncing

I implemented **Algolia** in my project like in this [example](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/flutter/) (without the filter) and it is working.

Now I would like to add a *debounce* so I do not search on every key stroke, but wait for example 500ms until search. That timer is reset if the user types in another letter.

I am using the suggested [HitsSearcher](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/flutter/) which has a `debounce` field, but changing that, didn't change anything for me. The results were still displayed instantly.

I also tried implementing this with a timer, and this causes the pause but after that pause, it is fired as often as new changes came in. So the timer is never actually cancelled.

In my `init`:

```
_searchTextEditingController.addListener(
  () => _startTimer(),
);
```

and `_startTimer()`:

```
 _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      () {
        print('finished');
        _userSearcher.applyState(
          (state) => state.copyWith(
            query: _searchTextEditingController.text,
            page: 0,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

So how can I achieve this? Im doing this to reduce the search requests on algolia.

Let me know if you need any more info!

**EDIT**

This question is not solved by the suggested question. Debounce is not working correctly and giving me wrong search results.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the `addListener` and instead use the suggested answer from the suggested question and put it inside my `onChanged`. My `_onSearchChanged` now looks like this:

```
  _onSearchChanged(String query) {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) {
      _debounce?.cancel();
    }

    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _userSearcher.applyState(
        (state) => state.copyWith(
          query: _searchTextEditingController.text,
          page: 0,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```